# How to get all results of a table with Many To Many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many, laravel-5.8, laravel-relations

I'm working on an Online Store project and I wanted to create **Add To Favourite** system for users to add products that they like to their favourite list.

So I have created a table named `favourite_products` which goes like this:

[image]

So the `usr_id` stands for user id and `prd_id` stands for product id.

Now I wanted to get all the data from this table.

So I tried adding this to the Controller:

```
$userFavourites = new User();
dd($userFavourites->favourites);
```

But it does not return data and shows this empty collection:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#2862 ▼
  #items: []
}
```

However data already exists there.

So my question is, how can I show all the results from `favourite_products` at a table with User Many To Many relationship?

Here is the `User.php` Model:

```
public function favourites()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'favourite_products', 'usr_id', 'prd_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

And this the `Product.php` Model:

```
public function favouritees()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'favourite_products', 'prd_id', 'usr_id');
    }
```

Comment: A _new_ user certainly doesn't have any favourites yet. Use the [Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) to get all favorites for all users

Comment: @brombeer But query builder does not look like to clean codes. Is there any Eloquent way for doing this except making a separated Model ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your goal is to get all the favorite product of all users, do

```
Product::whereHas('favouritees')->get();
```

you can also get a count with it

```
Product::whereHas('favouritees')->withCount('favouritees')->get();
```

Comment: if two different users add same product, it returns only one of them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70997829/how-can-i-do-this-with-eloquent-relationship

Comment: @yetep93258 yeah but the attribute favoritees_count will have 2 as value